# View images in browser with no extension

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I have a directory in my web app where I want to keep all the user profile pictures. Users can upload all types of images (png, jpg, gif). However, I want the image URL to be friendly, eg. http://example.com/static/picture/300-username, where the file is 300-username, but with no extension. I thought of removing the extension when the user uploads, and with a PHP controller, add a:

```
header('Content-Type: image/gif, image/x-xbitmap, image/jpeg, image/pjpeg, image/png');
readfile('http://example.com/static/picture/300-username');
```

This has worked well. I was wondering however, if this can be done by placing an .htaccess file in the picture directory, with some sort of Header, that whatever file is read in this directory, will display as picture. Is this possible?

Comment: Are you saving the files on the server without any file extension?

Comment: What's the downfall of implementing a Content-type like this? It works... I save it with no extension, so I don't have to detect which extension it is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don’t remove the extension, just offer extensionless URIs like `/static/picture/300-username`. Then add a line to your .htaccess:

```
Options +MultiViews
```

Apache will set the correct content type for you. See the documentation for [Content Negotiation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/content-negotiation.html).

Comment: Awesome! Even better than I expected.

Answer (score 1):

You can't specify multiple `Content-Type` like that.. You need to pass the correct header for each image served:

```
<?php
    $user = '300-username';
    $picture = 'http://example.com/static/picture/' . $user;
    $info = getimagesize($picture);
    $fp = fopen($picture, "rb");
    if ($info && $fp) {
        header("Content-type: {$info['mime']}");
        fpassthru($fp);
        exit;
    } else {
        // error
    }
?>
```

(Code adapted from PHP's [getimagesize()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php) documentation.)

Answer (score 0):

First your path need to be physically existent, else I don't think Apache can do anything for you.

However, here may be a workaround using a `RewriteRule`, keep the extension (by the way, I think it's bad practice to remove extension of a file, especially when they are not plain text files), and accept a requested file like `300-username` to rewrite to `300-username.jpg`.

Comment: If I keep the extension, how do I detect which one it is with ModRewrite?