# Do some browsers ignore image URLs with non-image (i.e. script) extensions?

Tags: php, image, url, file-extension, browser-security

I read that [extensionless image URLs are generally acceptable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5197990/view-images-in-browser-with-no-extension) with the correct content-type header set.

However, if a script generates image output and sets the content type, but the URL in the image tag is `.php` for instance, **will any browser deny the request as potentially malicious**?

For instance:

```
<?php
// myimage.php
header( 'Content-Type: image/jpeg' );
echo read_file_contents( 'someimage.jpg.in' );
```

and

```
<img src="myimage.php" />
```

Comment: hm, i think no :-) for browsers is the extension not relevant.

Comment: No major browser will. URLs are mostly just strings to them. Only ancient or misconfigured proxies might.

Comment: @Mario can you add as an answer? :)

Comment: Not entirely related to Question - You can block them with server settings (php.ini or .htaccess) though, you can make normal images just work and script files download automatically so that they won't get executed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No - a browser will not deny the request as potentially malicious.

A response header defining the content type is important for this approach.

Two examples:

- A lot of financial sites use this approach to generate their stock charts dynamically, (but most of them switched to JS solutions).
- The logo of the official PHP website is rendered that way.

  **http://php.net/images/logo.php[image: PHP Logo]**

  The response header contains "Content-Type:image/png".

  And this is the source-code for it: https://github.com/php/web-php/blob/master/images/logo.php

Answer (score 0):

The file extension is not relevant to the browser. The content in defined by the mime type.

In my experience have served MP3s, Images and many other files as ".php" on numerous websites with no problems.